# All emails working except new order email

Tags: magento-1.9

New order emails not being sent from week or so. All other emails are working. I tried to send order email to customer from admin side and it shows the message **"order email has been sent"** but its not sent.
Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: did you set email id in backend under sales > sales emails > order emials ?

Answer (score 0):

From `Magento 1.9` your order email sent from cronjob in your server cronjob you need to add `cron.sh` file when cron execute this file then your mail will be sent

**Solution 2:**

add https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html this extension, in system ->config of this extension you get one setting so you can remove the order mail from the queue and send in real time

Go to `system->configuration->Aschroder Extensions->Smtp pro-> Queue Configuration->Queue Usage` set it to never and your order email goes directly

Comment: cron.sh file is already there and cronjob is also set.

Comment: may be some error is there , please try to run cron.sh file manually from ssh access

Comment: `sh \your magentopath\cron.sh `

Answer (score 0):

```
goto the file: /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php
and create copy of file in
        /app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php
        and Change the code at Line 407

if ($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof
Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) {`enter code here`            

                          to


if (!($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof
Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue)) {
```